# How to set position of a passed text from first activity to second Activity?

Tags: android, eclipse

I passed a text from one activity to another activity

```
public void letter(View view)
{
    Intent intent =new Intent(this,LeaveActivity.class);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Second activity

```
public class LeaveActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Le.EXTRA_MESSAGE);



    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);


   setContentView(textView);

}
```

It displays the text in top left corner always, How to Set its position in 2nd activity, I want the text which in given in the first activity to be on the required position i needed in the second activity, Please help

Comment: show me your xml layout of second activity

Comment: you can create one layout for `LeaveActivity` and put your `textView` in  every where that you want

Comment: what is the position of textview in first activity??post the xml or screenshot.

Comment: My Second Activity contain nothing

Answer (score 1):

you have to set LayoutParams for TextView.

```
    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    textView.setGravity(GRAVITY.CENTER);
```

UPADTE:

```
   public class LeaveActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Le.EXTRA_MESSAGE);



      TextView textView = new TextView(this);
      textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      textView.setGravity(GRAVITY.CENTER);

      textView.setTextSize(40);
      textView.setTextColor(COLOR.RED);
      textView.setText(message);
      setContentView(textView);

   }
```

Comment: It shows a blank result, the text that i entered in 1st activity is not showing in the 2nd activty's page

Comment: i was following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: It create a new activity, but the text entered in the first activity always will be in top. I need to set the position of it ,PLEASE HELP

Comment: When the button is clicked, the activity is crashed